# erlang R25.3 compile failed

Tags: erlang

I try to install R25.3 by kerl, but compile failed.But I have some problems when compiling it.
This is my macos version: 13.4 (22F66)
My mac uses intel chip.

This is the errors when I compiling R25.3:

```
 CC ../priv/obj/x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0/cmac.o
 CC ../priv/obj/x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0/common.o
 CC ../priv/obj/x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0/dh.o
dh.c:93:63: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'unsigned long *' to parameter of type 'uint64_t *' (aka 'unsigned long long *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        params[i++] = OSSL_PARAM_construct_uint64("priv_len", &len);
                                                              ^~~~
/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/params.h:77:67: note: passing argument to parameter 'buf' here
OSSL_PARAM OSSL_PARAM_construct_uint64(const char *key, uint64_t *buf);
                                                                  ^
dh.c:98:12: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);
           ^
dh.c:98:12: note: did you mean 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_provided'?
/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/evp.h:1469:15: note: 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_provided' declared here
EVP_PKEY_CTX *EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_provided(OPENSSL_CTX *libctx,
              ^
dh.c:98:10: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX *' (aka 'struct evp_pkey_ctx_st *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);
         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dh.c:100:9: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(pctx) <= 0) {
        ^
dh.c:100:9: note: did you mean 'EVP_PKEY_key_fromdata_init'?
/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/evp.h:1562:5: note: 'EVP_PKEY_key_fromdata_init' declared here
int EVP_PKEY_key_fromdata_init(EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx);
    ^
dh.c:104:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR'
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata(pctx, &pkey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, params) <= 0) {
                                       ^
dh.c:111:16: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_pkey'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    pctx_gen = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_pkey(NULL, pkey, NULL);
               ^
dh.c:111:14: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX *' (aka 'struct evp_pkey_ctx_st *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    pctx_gen = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_pkey(NULL, pkey, NULL);
             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dh.c:123:10: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_generate'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (!EVP_PKEY_generate(pctx_gen, &pkey_gen)) {
         ^
dh.c:130:10: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (!EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param(pkey_gen, "pub",  &pub_key_gen)) {
         ^
dh.c:206:17: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    peer_pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);
                ^
dh.c:206:15: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX *' (aka 'struct evp_pkey_ctx_st *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    peer_pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);
              ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dh.c:208:9: error: call to undeclared function 'EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(peer_pctx) <= 0)
        ^
dh.c:210:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR'
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata(peer_pctx, &peer_pkey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, params) <= 0)
                                                 ^
dh.c:217:14: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'EVP_PKEY_CTX *' (aka 'struct evp_pkey_ctx_st *') from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    own_pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "DH", NULL);
             ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
dh.c:222:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR'
    if (EVP_PKEY_fromdata(own_pctx, &own_pkey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, params) <= 0)
                                               ^
5 warnings and 10 errors generated.
```

This is my clang verison:
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Does it means my clang version is confilict with erlang R25.3?

Is there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: Can you show what you used for configuring the build? For example, if you use a `~/.kerlrc` file for settings, please show the value of the `KERL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS` variable.

Comment: I use the default option.   No ~/.kerlrc file

Comment: We've switched from kerl to asdf, it is much more convenient for local environments. Deployment anyway done with prepared linux packages.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.erlang.org/docs/25/installation_guide/install

Pay attention to the following explanation.

On builds without crypto, ssl and ssh there is a failed test case for `undefined` functions. Verify that the failed test case log *only* shows calls to skipped applications.

`EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR` is part of ssl.

Comment: thanks. I install R25.3 successfully after installing openssl@3.